# How to connect the 2nd-generation Chromecast with my TPLink WR841N router?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, chromecast

I wanted to upgrade my first-generation Chromecast with the new one.

I can connect to the new Chromecast on its own provided network. Yet during the setup, once I enter the correct passphrase for my WiFi network, it loops forever only to fail again and again.

My router is a TPLINK-WR841N Hardware version v8. I have the latest firmware installed, I even resetted the router still to no avail.

The closest issue I could find to this problem was this old [thread](http://forum.tp-link.com/showthread.php?78600-Chromecast-fails-on-TL-WR841N), yet this is related to old Chromecast which did work fine for me, even though the issue described fits my problem to exactly.

How to connect my 2nd-generation Chromecast to my WiFi network?

Comment: First chromecast was plagued with compatibility issues. I suspect v2 may have similar teething issues. Create a hotspot on your phone and see if it will connect to that.

Comment: @Linef4ult I cannot connect to my phone as I need the phone to set it up. I can however connect to an unsecured network, as I have set up a Freifunk for the people in my area. Still, not optimal. Yet it seems the Chromecast has issues with the router than being outright broken.

Comment: Are you using WPA2-PSK with the secured access point @k0pernikus ?

Comment: @Linef4ult Beat you to it, I tried all the different secure settings from WPA2 TKIP and AES as well as the WPA standard and mixed mode. I will not try WEP for obvious reasons ;)

Comment: Covered all the bases so. Might be worth trying an 8 digit long numeric only PSK, I've seen that work with "picky" devices. Other than that though just wait for google to update it.

Comment: @Linef4ult That what my no-password free-for-all access point already did. Alas, after the update, the chromecast still won't connect to the secured access point.

Answer (score 0):

I have bought myself a new router, in my case an TP-LINK Archer C9. This time it worked from the get-go, so I assume my old router was to blame.

As to why my TL-WR841N refused to work still eludes me, it yet [it also doesn't show on the supported router list](https://support.google.com/chromecast/table/6207416).

Answer (score 0):

[It doesn't support 5Ghz](https://support.google.com/chromecast/table/6207416?hl=en) which is needed by Chromecast 2nd version.

Comment: Do you have a source?

Comment: https://support.google.com/chromecast/table/6207416?hl=en

Comment: This is not true. 1. He could connect to open network on same router. 2. The compatibility list shows many 2.4GHz-only devices. 3. I've once installed the v2 on a 2.4GHz-only network! Weird that this router is not supported, as it is a quite common device (I have one myself, but no chromecast in MY household). Maybe update the firmware of the router?

Comment: @TJJ This gets even weirder now. The firmware was up to date and my new router supports 5GHz, so it seemed plausible. Do you have the 2nd edition Chromecast working on just a 2.4Ghz router?

Comment: Not me personally, but I bought and set up a 2nd edition CC for my mom. She is using a 2.4GHz-only Fritzbox 3170. Have you tried running DD-WRT on your WR841N (I have the WR841N running at my house with DD-WRT)?

Comment: @TJJ No, DD-WRT is something I could test. Though, it doesn't seem likely that I get around to it anytime soon.

Comment: It is quite easy. Not much more than a normal firmware update. Here's a comprehensive guide: http://greggborodaty.com/installing-dd-wrt-tp-link-tl-wr841n/ (use the v8 version throughout though).

Comment: You might also wanna try downgrading the official firmware to 130506, as suggested in this youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=33L4OYVJRf0